# Facebook comment random image

Tags: php, css, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Good Morning

some sites, writing in facebook comments for example "domain.site/yourname, 
the generated commentary will contain a random preview image assigned to the name.
The thing is pretty viral and I would like to make prove with my site.
Only once the browser cache loads an image will it be stored even by entering other word.

```css
<meta property="og:title"           content="$Variable_catch_name /> 
<meta property="og:image"           content="$Variable_link" />
```

I try with php and open graph facebook,but the result is always the same image.

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit better? I would like to help you but I find your question quite hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic og tags, you need to create separate urls. Use a parameter in your url to make it unique, for example:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://yourdomain.com/?id=xxx" />
```

It´s not the browser, it´s facebook caching your og tags.